# Cant boot FreeBSD 10.1 using grub2

Tags: ubuntu, boot, grub, freebsd

I installed FreeBSD 10.1 on a machine that has Xubuntu already. The installation completed successfully but im not able to boot it. On my grub boot screen i get only 2 options: ubuntu and advanced options.

In particular i entered the Xubuntu partition to see whats going on. If i do: `os-prober` i get:

```
/dev/sda1:unknown Linux distribution:Linux:linux
/dev/sda2:unknown Linux distribution:Linux1:linux
```

This is my fdisk -l output:

root@diet-atlante:/home/user# fdisk -l

```
Disk /dev/sda: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes
255 testine, 63 settori/tracce, 121601 cilindri, totale 1953525168 settori
Unità = settori di 1 * 512 = 512 byte
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Identificativo disco: 0x2e70fb76

    Dispositivo Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
    /dev/sda1      1134323757  1448896490   157286367   a5  FreeBSD
    Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary.
    /dev/sda2   *  1448896554  1953525104   252314275+  a5  FreeBSD
    Partition 2 does not start on physical sector boundary.
    /dev/sda4            2048  1134323711   567160832    5  Esteso
    /dev/sda5            4096  1002164223   501080064   83  Linux
    /dev/sda6      1002166272  1022167039    10000384   82  Linux swap / Solaris
```

So i guess grub doen't recognise the FreeBSD partition. Any solutions?
Thanks

Comment: Did you reconfigure your grub?

Comment: this solved the problem unix.stackexchange.com/a/109278/34969. hope it helps anyone who needs help.