# Unable to boot FreeBSD 12.1 using GRUB

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, grub, freebsd

This is not a duplicate question to https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/109272/add-freebsd-to-grub2-boot-menu or [Cant boot FreeBSD 10.1 using grub2](https://superuser.com/questions/1005363/cant-boot-freebsd-10-1-using-grub2).

Firstly I tried the mechanism suggested in https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/110091/377563 but that does not work. GRUB shows FreeBSD as an option but says that `kfreebsd` is not a valid command or something of that sort.
I am presently trying the code mentioned in https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2%20Other%20Os#Direct_Kernel_Boot. However, `sudo update-grub` or `sudo grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg` shows a bug which was noted in the previous try as well, saying that it has `Found unknown Linux distribution on /dev/sda16` which is where FreeBSD is supposed to be.

Comment: What is the question here?

Comment: @masgo well, none of the techniques are working. How can I boot FreeBSD in that case?